Statistical Testing with Minimal Samples for Reinforcement Learning Algorithms
I'm working on comparing two reinforcement learning algorithms where:

Running experiments is extremely computationally expensive
Based on preliminary results, Algorithm B consistently and
substantially outperforms Algorithm A (the current state-of-the-art)
Traditional approaches suggest ~10 runs per algorithm for statistical
significance Each run produces a scalar performance metric

Given these constraints and the expected large effect size, what statistical approaches would minimize the required number of runs while still providing rigorous evidence of superiority? I'm particularly interested in:

Sequential testing methods that could terminate early given clear
superiority
Statistical tests specifically designed for small samples with large
effects
Appropriate power analysis given these constraints

What would be the minimum number of runs needed to establish statistical significance in this scenario?"
